# acceso denegado de root@localhost en phpmyadmin xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, login, contraseña

No se que he tocado en phpmyadmin pero ahora no me deja acceder al usuario root@localhost (donde tenía todas las bases de datos). Por contra, cuando pongo cualquier usuario me deja acceder sin problema como "anonymous user".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiando el pass con el Shell de XAMPP

[image: Shell]

Cuando se abra la ventana del Shell pones

```
mysqladmin -u root password
```

El shell te pedirá que ingreses una nueva contraseña. Presiona Enter/Return  nuevamente y se le pedirá que confirme la nueva contraseña y listo.

Otra forma es con el **config.inc.php** que esta en la carpeta **phpMyAdmin**.

Ahí buscas la línea y cambias el pass que quieras

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YourPassword';
```

o Le dices que no use passwords

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

[image: Config]